# Ektron Library images not displaying; filepath not found

Tags: c#, image, path, directory, ektron

I have a bunch of images that are stored in the Library in Ektron. I'm trying to display these images on one of my webpages in a slideshow. Here's what I have:

```
public partial class WebAssets_UserControls_uxSlideShow : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List<String> images { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<LibraryData> libraryImageList = GetLibraryDataList(1);

        var imageList = (from im in libraryImageList
            where im.FolderName == "Alumni"
            select im).ToList();

        var imageUrls = imageList.Select(image => image.FileName).ToList();

        SlideShowRepeater.DataSource = imageUrls;
        SlideShowRepeater.DataBind();

    }

    private List<LibraryData> GetLibraryDataList(int libraryTypeId)
    {
        LibraryManager libraryManager = new LibraryManager(ApiAccessMode.LoggedInUser);
        LibraryCriteria criteria = new LibraryCriteria(LibraryProperty.Id, EkEnumeration.OrderByDirection.Descending);
        criteria.AddFilter(LibraryProperty.TypeId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, libraryTypeId);
     //   criteria.AddFilter(LibraryData.FolderName, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, libraryFolderName);
        List<LibraryData> libraryDataList = libraryManager.GetList(criteria);
        return libraryDataList;
    }

}
```

and the HTML...

```
<div id="slideShowImages" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <asp:Repeater ID="SlideShowRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <img alt="Alumni Events" src="<%# Container.DataItem %>" height="240" width="632" />
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The image URLs I'm pulling aren't working though. The paths aren't found. The paths for the images looks like this:

```
/uploadedimages/Alumni/001.jpg
```

I figure the reason they're not displaying is because I don't have an uploadedimages folder in my project, rather that folder is located in Ektron, but I don't know what to change to make the images display.

Comment: I suggest you plug in one of the container's generated URL's in the img src attribute, and see if that will get a displayed image.  I suspect the URLs need to be set up to reach the folder properly.

Comment: Please explain your setup a little more. You say you don't have an uploadedimages folder? Are you not running this code inside an Ektron website?

Answer (score 1):

Ektron assumes that the images are local by default.

You'll either have to modify the path to be absolute, provided that your Ektron instance is public, e.g. http://www.example.com/uploadedImages/Alumni/001.jpg

or:

If the Ektron install is not public, as in a 3-Tier deployment, then you have three options:

1. Have your application make a webrequest to essentially act as a proxy to serve files from the Ektron installation to the client.
2. Move the files from Ektron into your application using a tool like Robocopy or XCopy. You could even promote the files from your Ektron server to your project via an [Ektron Extension (aka Strategy)](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/EDR/Web/EDR.htm#Strategies/Strategies.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____6). In the documentation, Expand All and search within the page for *LibraryStrategy*.
3. Use a network share or virtual directory within IIS to allow the application to behave as if the files are local to your project even though they are still hosted within Ektron.